# Catkin and eclipse

Tags: ros, catkin, eclipse, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i am using ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

I want edit my packages in eclipse. On Fuerte i runed make eclipse-project and import this result as eclipse project.

At groovy i can include my catkin workspace as project. This is working.

But now i have a problems with my includes.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"

warning: Unresolved inclusion.
```

Or

```
ROS_INFO("text") error: Type 'std_msgs::String::ConstPtr' could not be resolved
```

and i couldnt see with crtl + mouse the functions.

What i do wrong ? what i must edit in eclipse that this is working?

thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52013/catkin-and-eclipse/) by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 222 on 2013-01-11

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is how I do this. Go to your workspace directory and run catkin_make with options to generate eclipse project files:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

The project files will be generated in the build/ folder. Now source the workspace setup and start eclipse from the terminal:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
eclipse
```

This allows eclipse to get the correct environment to be able to build from within eclipse. Now import the project from the build/ folder. Eclipse provides a link named "Source directory" within the project so that you can edit the source code. Using this method, the indexer resolves all symbols correctly, and Eclipse is also able to build the workspace successfully.

---

Originally posted by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) with karma: 529 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 15

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-01-23**:
thank you for the answer i can build my project in eclipse now. But in source directory in my files i have stille the problem that my functions could not be resolved. For example Function 'ROS_INFO_STREAM' could not be resolved. But i can build it. I dont understand why.

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-01-23**:
Is it possible that i must change my library path manuel? that he can resolve this?

**Comment by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) on 2013-01-23**:
This should work out of the box. Go to Project Properties -> C++ Include Paths, and make sure that all the required ROS include directories are present, like /opt/ros/groovy/include. Also try rebuilding the index if it's never been done before (Right click on project -> Index -> Rebuild).

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-29**:
If I execute /catkin_make -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"/ then the action is just normal catkin_make and no eclipse project is created. Any ideas why? Or how to find the eclipse project in build/? I can't see anything new.

**Comment by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) on 2013-01-29**:
Do you see the .project and .cproject files in the build/ directory? These are what allow Eclipse to import the project, using File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace, and then select the build directory. It should then show you the auto-generated project which you can import.

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-29**:
No .project or .cproject anywhere.

**Comment by [r0nald](https://answers.ros.org/users/3908/r0nald/) on 2013-01-29**:
The problem was, that if all projects were compiled, then catkin_make did not invoke cmake and cmake did not get the command to make eclipse files. Eclipse files get generated if catkin_make clean was done previously or if I force cmake with the -force-cmake flag.

**Comment by [kalakris](https://answers.ros.org/users/17/kalakris/) on 2013-01-30**:
Thanks for the information. I've updated the answer above to include --force-cmake.

**Comment by [Mahisorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/2624/mahisorn/) on 2013-04-15**:
For a better result, create a Makefile project with the generated Makefile. This will resolve system include path problem (e.g. /../c++/4.6, ...).

PS In project settings, we can change Build behavior from "all" to "-j8 -l8" to make it faster to compile.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-02**:
@kalakris Thx for the great method! 2 clarifications that worked for me: (1) A single .project is to be generated under `/build` directly (I first looked for `/build/%EACH_PKG%`. (2) To "import" projects, instead of "File-->import", use "File-->New-->C++ Project" and specify the projects' directory.

**Comment by [Mudassir Khan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4582/mudassir-khan/) on 2013-07-11**:
I cant find any .project even after executing the above commands. When I try to import the project it only find one project in catkin_ws directory which is Project@build(/home/username/catkin_ws/build . Should not it generate a separate project for each package in my catkin_ws directory.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-07-11**:
For each CMake invocation you will get one Eclipse project. So when you invoke it on a catkin workspace you will get one project for the whole workspace.

**Comment by [raghav.rao32](https://answers.ros.org/users/22735/raghav.rao32/) on 2015-06-11**:
@Mudassir Khan, @r0nald remember that to show hidden files in your file manager since .project and .cproject they begin with a '.' and are thus hidden by default

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. cd to your /src
2. run the following: cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j8 .

This should solve your problem

---

Originally posted by [Quizzarex](https://answers.ros.org/users/3951/quizzarex/) with karma: 33 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hunk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3946/hunk/) on 2013-01-21**:
do you have an other idea? it is not working. but thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The accepted answer works for generating the project files out of source (The catkin way).

For an in source generation of the files use Quizzarex's answer:
You can do this in any folder containing a `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j8
```

(I created a new answer because in comments formatting is not possible.)

---

Originally posted by [fivef](https://answers.ros.org/users/4680/fivef/) with karma: 2756 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Francisco Vina](https://answers.ros.org/users/2813/francisco-vina/) on 2013-11-08**:
Using this command worked better for me. Otherwise by doing cmake on the entire src folder there were some header files that Eclipse was not able to link to

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2014-06-17**:
Creating a new answer is the correct thing to do regardless of formatting. Additional answers are too often put in comment chains.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-06-20**:
This method will partly defeat the purpose of having catkin style packages (with source and build directories separate).

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-09-24**:
To remove the whole garbage that gets generated do `rm -r catkin catkin_generated/ CMakeCache.txt CMakeFiles/ cmake_install.cmake  CTestTestfile.cmake devel/ gtest/ Makefile  test_results/`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if this will help anyone in particular but I've been trying to fix these link errors off and on for about a week now so I thought I'd share what I've found.

Ubuntu 12.04, ROS Hydro, Catkin, and Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2

So I've been trying to get my code into my Eclipse IDE.  I ran the set up described in the IDE tutorial here,
http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

I then imported as the tutorial asked but got all sorts of link error issues... kept deleting the project and retrying the steps and checking to make sure that all components of C++ were installed for eclipse indigo.  Tried manually adding libraries, but I was getting simple link errors like std::string.

Nothing in here really seemed to help with link errors.  Until I noticed fivef and Quizzarex's answers here. I then went to workspace/src folder and ran the following,

```
cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_ECLIPSE_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j8
```

Then in eclipse I imported the existing project from the workspace/src folder.

This worked much nicer as far as removing unnecessary clutter from your Project Explorer in Eclipse since it added only my catkin projects as they are and not my all my project build folders along with a separate linked [Source directories] directory.  Although there probably is a solution to that using the prior method from the build folder.

To my surprise this method also removed my linking errors.

---

If your still having errors you may want to try using Eclipse Kepler.

I started using and noticed a new feature called "Re-resolve Unresolved Includes".  This is actually when I noticed that my Workspace/src folder worked after running "Re-resolve Unresolved Includes" in Kepler... but I've since tried remaking the Eclipse Project and importing, as I mentioned above from the workspace/src directory, and haven't been able to reproduce the unresolved link errors.

Hope this helps, I guess its kind of a redundant post to fivef's and Quizzarex's answers but I was finally happy to see no link errors and thought I'd mention my solution.

---

Originally posted by [ncr7](https://answers.ros.org/users/2800/ncr7/) with karma: 325 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that eclipse runs from a shell - that has all the env variables set up - the best thing to do is the following:

1. Go to the "your catkin_workspace"/build directory.
2. Either create a new directory for the package that you are about to compile or enter the already built package.
3. So now the working directory is "your catkin_workspace"/build/"package_name":

From here run:

```
cmake ../../src/"package_name" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../install -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=../../devel -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

Viola!

This is better for two clear advantages:=

Firstly, you have different .project files for every project. This means that you can **import them separately in eclipse**.
Secondly, this also means that when you build from within eclipse, the entire workspace is not built. **Only the current project is built.**

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2